# How can I structure my flask project and refactor routes into seperate files

Tags: python, flask

Currently I've got all my flask routes in a single file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import jsonify, make_response


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
@app.route('/skills')
def skillchart():
    return render_template('skills.html')



@app.route('/api/skills')
def getSkills():
    skills = {
        "HTML": [], #jsonify does not support arrays, but only dictionaries.
        "CSS": [],  # also I might add skills with subskills
        "SASS": [],
        "Bootstrap": []
    }
    return jsonify(skills)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

How can I best refactor the routes in seperate files?(Without circular imports)

Comment: you can use blueprints

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/) or import the modules containing the routes.

```
/app
    __init__.py     
    /views
      |- x.py
      |- y.py
      |- z.py
```

Then the only thing you have to do is to import the modules after the flask application is initialized (e.g. in `__init__.py`).

```
app = Flask(__name__)
...
import views.x
import views.y
import views.z
```

All the routes now registered in your app. However, you should not call functions from the imported modules because it creates circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Using blueprints as suggested turned out to be the best way.

First I refactored the views into a seperate file and defined a blueprint in it.

```
#views/skills.py
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import jsonify, make_response

api_blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)


@api_blueprint.route('/api/skills/frontend')
def getSkills():
    skills = {
        "HTML/CSS": [
            "SASS",
            "Bootstrap"
        ]
    }
    return jsonify(skills)




@api_blueprint.route('/api/skills/backend')
def getBackendSkills():
    skills = {
        "Java": [],
        "Python": [
            "Django",
            "Flask"
        ],
        "Ruby": [
            "Ruby on Rails"
        ],
        "PHP": [
            "Laravel"
        ],
        "SQL": []
    }
    return jsonify(skills)

@api_blueprint.route('/api/skills/mixed')
def getMixedSkills():
    skills = {
        "Javascript": {
            'Frontend': [
                "angular.js",
                "knockout.js",
                "coffeescript",
                "jquery"
            ],
            'Backend': [
                "Node.js",
                "Express.js"
            ]
        }
    }
    return jsonify(skills)
```

Then I import and register the blueprint in the main file (app.py)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from views.skills import api_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True




app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)

@app.route('/skills')
def skillchart():
    return render_template('skills.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

This works just fine.